# How Do I Setup OpenVPN and Nginx To Allow Sharing Port 443?

Tags: openvpn, nginx, webserver, ssl

How Do I Setup OpenVPN and Nginx To Allow Sharing Port 443?
I Want To Be Able to use the VPN, but also at the same time, serve web requests from the same server. :-)

Comment: See https://jarrousse.org/getting-openvpn-and-nginx-to-share-port-443/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If both programs want to use port `443`, and you can't configure one of them to use a different port, you're out of luck.

Imagine a single Ethernet packet arriving at your system, aimed at port `443`. Which program handles it?

Comment: This solves the OP problem completely: https://jarrousse.org/getting-openvpn-and-nginx-to-share-port-443/